# inserting image in db table failes

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I have db table `Person` which has columns like

```
Id | Name | Dob | ....
```

now I added one more column `CompanyLogo` of type `varbinary(MAX)`
which will is now null. Since I have more than 1000 records in Person table I want to insert on the fly using sql statement some default image for CompanyLogo. Later trough ui this image wil be changed for each person, but that's not the scope of this question.

I tried with code

```
@"begin
     UPDATE Person SET [CompanyLogo] = (SELECT
     CompanyLogo.* from Openrowset(Bulk
     'd:\test.png', Single_Blob) TestCompanyLogo)                    
    end
  "
```

but I'm getting following exception

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have error in your query. Try this.

```
BEGIN
     UPDATE Person 
         SET [CompanyLogo] = (SELECT TestCompanyLogo.* 
                              FROM OPENROWSET(BULK 'd:\test.png', SINGLE_BLOB) TestCompanyLogo)                    
END
```